# Using Python's `unittest` module to compose tests of functions in a separate file

Tags: python, unit-testing, build, conventions, project-organization

I have an issue with getting my unit tests to resolve calls to the S.U.T.'s functions. The S.U.T. is defined in a separate file, but in the same project. I've considerable Python experience, but I've never tried to deploy code in a conventional way (which generally suggests conventional testing). The directory structure I'm using seems to be in line with PyPI convention, but I'm missing the step on executing unit tests.

**Note 1:** I have tried reviewing the official `unittest` module's API documentation & tutorials, as well as some unofficial docs. There's not a lot bridging the gap between new, undeployed project and downloading projects already deployed.

**Note 2:** I'm not interested in using any third-party unit testing framework. I'd like to stick to `unittest` module and its conventions. I'm hoping to keep the original project as cross-platform and third-party dependency-light as possible.

**Note 3:** Adding `import mfut` or `from mfut import conditionallyClose` statements to `all_tests.py` results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mfut'`. I'm sure this has something to do with the `PYTHONPATH`, but changing that environment variable strikes me as fragile. I'm hoping there's a more robust way.

Below is merely an example toy problem, but the test cases for the original project aren't much more sophisticated.

---

Given the following Python 3 project directory structure:

```
My Fun Unit Testing
    ├───src
    │   └───mfut
    │       └───mfut.py
    │
    └───tests
        └───all_tests.py
```

and the following contents of file `mfut.py`:

```
import math
def conditionallyClose(x1, x2):
    if math.abs(x1) < 1:
        return math.isclose(x1, x2)
    if math.abs(x1) < 1e6:
        return math.isclose(x1, x2, rel_tol=0.10)
    return math.isclose(x1, x2, rel_tol=0.001)
```

and the following contents of `all_tests.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from math import inf
class onlyTestCase(TestCase):
    def testConditionallyClose_mag1(self):
        self.assertTrue(conditionallyClose(0.05, 0.06))

    def testConditionallyClose_mag6(self):
        self.assertTrue(conditionallyClose(1200000, 1085000))

    def testConditionallyClose_magInf(self):
        self.assertTrue(conditionallyClose(inf, inf))
```

what is the Python 3 convention (or requirement) for getting the `conditionallyClose(...)` calls in `all_tests.py` to resolve?

Comment: Same way you get the TestCase and inf to resolve: you import it.

Comment: Adding `from mfut import conditionallyClose` statement results in: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mfut'`

Comment: You will need to add your `src` folder to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : Is there a more robust, project-scoped way? I'd rather not have to store the original value of the environment variable, append to that value, perform my tests, and then revert it. Not to mention requiring any other devs to do the same to their environments. Virtual environments have the same issue: it's a headache to configure.

Comment: @DanC.Wlodarski Another solution is to put your `tests` directory as a sibling to your `mfut` directory.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : I thought that doesn't jive with PyPI's build/deploy convention.

Comment: @DanC.Wlodarski Maybe not. I haven't built a package to deploy with pypi before.

Comment: If you are running from the command line, you can set `PYTHONPATH` temporarily in the command: `PYTHONPATH=./src pytest`, for example. This makes it much simpler than you described in your earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that python cannot recognize any library with the name `mfut`. If you import it like this `from mfut import conditionallyClose`, **it must be either a library, or a file in the same directory as your current python file**.

To solve this problem, take these steps:

1. First of all make sure that your project file structure is like this:
   [image]
2. [Create a setup.py file](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for you project (you can also [use PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-setup-py.html) to do it) and put it in the root directory of you project (which in this case is "B:\Repos\SampleProject").
3. [Activate your virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and run `pip install -e .` in the root of you project directory. This will use the setup.py and make python run your code as a python library and refer to the code dynamically from your files.
4. Now you can import your code like this from any file:

   `from src.mfut.mfut import conditionallyClose`

Comment: "it must be either a library, or a file in the same directory as your current python file." More accurately, it must be a python file in the list of paths which python searches.

Comment: `from src.mfut.mfut import conditionallyClose` Most likely the OP doesn't want to include `src` in the import.

Comment: I'll give that solution a try and report back, Mohammad. Thanks!